# How to make lookup of all fields in a table in ax 2012?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

[image]

I have a form where the user can select any available table in the AOT in a dropdown/combobox  (no. 1 where it says salestable)

Now i want to make a lookup in no.2 of all fields in the table selected in no. 1. I need to get this just based on the table name...
I wish for the lookup to contain both the system name of the field and the label of the field.
Is this possible? I have tried a good deal of solutions but i haven't been able to get it yet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have blogged about this, so please take a look:
http://devexpp.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/dynamics-ax-custom-lookup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my final solution:

I made a regular table (TableFieldLookupTmp) containing the fields: tableId, label and field.
I insert into this table from dicttable loop.

If the table already has been added before, i just do the lookup.
It works fast.

Thanks for the help, guys.

```
public void lookup()
```

{

SysTableLookup      SysTableLookup;

```
TableFieldLookupTmp TableFieldLookupTmp;

QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;
QueryBuildRange     queryBuildRange;
Query query         = new Query();

tableName           tableName = 'SalesTable';
int tmpTableid =    tablename2id(tableName);
int i;

DictField           dictField;
DictTable dictTable = new DictTable(tableName2id(tableName)); 

if(!(select TableFieldLookupTmp where TableFieldLookupTmp.TablenumId == tmpTableid).recid)
{
    ttsBegin;
    if (dictTable)
    {
        for (i=1; i<=dictTable.fieldCnt(); i++)
        {
            dictField = new DictField(dictTable.id(), dictTable.fieldCnt2Id(i));

            if(subStr(dictField.name(),0,4) == "DEL_")
                continue;
            else
            {
                TableFieldLookupTmp.Label = dictField.label();
                TableFieldLookupTmp.field = dictField.name();
                TableFieldLookupTmp.TableNumId = tmpTableid;
                TableFieldLookupTmp.insert();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error(strFmt("Table '%1' not found!", tableName));
    }
    ttsCommit;

}


sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(TableFieldLookupTmp), this);

sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(TableFieldLookupTmp, field));
sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(TableFieldLookupTmp, label));

queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(TableFieldLookupTmp));
queryBuildDataSource.addSortField(fieldNum(TableFieldLookupTmp, field), SortOrder::Ascending);
queryBuildRange = queryBuildDataSource.addRange(fieldNum(TableFieldLookupTmp, TablenumId));
queryBuildRange.value(int2str(tmpTableid));

//queryBuildRange.value('!DEL_*');

sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();

//super();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to do it I can think of off hand.  Reflection and using the `SysModelELements` table.  The first way will give you the name & label, the second will not give you labels reliably.

The first job demonstrates this with reflection.  The second shows it with the `SysModelElements` tables, and is faster, but won't give you the label.  You can use a `DictField` object to enumerate the label (as shown in the second method).

The first method is the most reliable as the second could have some cases I haven't thought about such as table views or maps.

**Method 1:**

```
static void Job96(Args _args)
{
    str             tableName = 'SalesTable';
    DictTable       dictTable;
    DictField       dictField;
    int             i;

    dictTable = new DictTable(tableName2id(tableName));

    if (dictTable)
    {
        for (i=1; i<=dictTable.fieldCnt(); i++)
        {
            dictField = new DictField(dictTable.id(), dictTable.fieldCnt2Id(i));
            info(strFmt("Field Name: '%1'; Field Label: '%2'; IsSystem: %3",
                        dictField.name(),
                        dictField.label(),
                        dictField.isSystem()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error(strFmt("Table '%1' not found!", tableName));
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
static void Job97(Args _args)
{
    tableName           tableName = 'SalesTable';
    SysModelElement     tables;
    SysModelElement     fields;
    DictField           dictField;

    while select tables
        where tables.ElementType            == UtilElementType::Table       &&
              tables.Name                   == tableName
        join fields
            where fields.ElementType        == UtilElementType::TableField  &&
                  fields.ParentModelElement == tables.RecId
    {
        dictField = new DictField(tables.AxId, fields.AxId);

        info(strFmt("Field Name: '%1'; Field Label: '%2'; IsSystem: %3",
                        dictField.name(),
                        dictField.label(),
                        dictField.isSystem()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is nice, but how do i put this in a lookup? It seems i cant put dictable in a querybuilder to perform the lookup...

Comment: One way is to create a temp table and populate it on the fly.  Getting a lookup to contain the field label is the difficult part because field labels are language specific.  They are stored somewhere in the model database, but because of label caching, they aren't entirely predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the forms SysQueryForm and SysQueryFieldLookUp. There you can see, how the standard handles this Problem.